# Incomplete CSS animation on first execution after load (but complete thereafter)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-animations

I am working on this website for my wife's business: https://derma-fischeln.iuga-popescu.ro/nomad_force/ and I am having trouble with one animation.

I started the website using a template, to which I am trying to make several changes.

I made a logo slide and fade in when scrolling to the bottom of the window using these code snippets:

JQuery

```
// HIDE AND SHOW SMALL LOGO ON SCROLL 
if (y > heroHeight){
  $("#hiddenLogo").addClass('navbar-brand-visible');
  $("#hiddenLogo").removeClass('navbar-brand-invisible');
} 
if (y == 0){
  $("#hiddenLogo").addClass('navbar-brand-invisible');
  $("#hiddenLogo").removeClass('navbar-brand-visible');
}
```

CSS

```
.navbar-brand-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s, -moz-transform 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);  
}

.navbar-brand-invisible {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s, -moz-transform 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
  transform: translateY(10px);  
}
```

I am not a professional, so this might not be the best way, but it worked well initially. Then, I made some changes to add a color transition on scroll to the background of the *navbar* style and now the animation has an issue.

The very first execution of the animation in *navbar-brand-visible* style after loading the site is incomplete. The animation is just a fade in, whereas it should also slide up. From the second execution, it's OK, with fade and slide (can be reproduced by scrolling to the top and back to the bottom of the page).

It's the same behavior on Firefox and Chrome (desktop, under Linux).

I tried to revert the steps I made when I added the changes to the navbar background, but I was no longer able to go so far back as to obtain the initial behavior. Unfortunately, I don't know which exact change broke the animation.

I will appreciate your support.

**Later edit:**
I just noticed one thing, which may or may not be related. If the page is scrolled down at the point where `y > heroHeight` and I click the refresh button of the browser, the behavior is inconsistent. Sometimes, the page loads and the logo appears (with the incomplete animation). Other times, the navbar is transparent and the logo doesn't appear.

Comment: The translation is set only when one of the `navbar-brand-visible` or `navbar-brand-invisible` classes are applied. Initially none is applied so the computed value is already `transform: translateY(0px)` and there is nothing to transition when you apply the `navbar-brand-visible` class. Set the invisible class by default. Also beware, one can refresh the page and end up already in some scrolled down position, you may want to execute all your scroll based updates at page load too.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you! You pointed me to the right path, even though the solution was a bit different. The element to which this is applied is defined as `<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" id="hiddenLogo">` and I thought the class `navbar-brand` already had `transform: translateY(10px);`. But it didn't. So I added the line to `navbar-brand` (with opacity 0) and now it's OK. Thank you also for the second point. Indeed, I had noticed that issue (I guess it's the reason for my later edit) and still have to find a solution for it. I just didn't get there yet. :)